# Django: query latest posts from different categories

Tags: django, django-views

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = ...
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    date = .......

class Category(models.Model):
    title = ....
```

On the main page i want to display 5 posts with latest dates, but all posts must be from different categories. There is 50 categoriese, for example. Is it possible?

Comment: Couldn't you query the 5 most recently updated Categories and afterwards fetch the top post from each of these categories?

Comment: Don't have field "update time" for category... Or you mean, i can somehow retrieve it through the query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Max

categories = Category.objects.annotate(most_recent=Max(post__date)).order_by('-most_recent')[:5]

posts = list()
for category in categories:
  posts.append(category.post_set.latest())
```

That annotates the categories with the date of the most recent post as the value of `most_recent`, which you can then order by to get the 5 most recent categories.

Then, just loop through the categories and pull out the latest post for each. Done.

Answer (score 1):

You bet it's possible.

Randomly select 5 categories

Grab the most recent post for each category

Perhaps something like:

```
randposts = {} #list for most recent posts of 5 randomly selected categories
for randomcat in Category.objects.order_by('?')[5:]:
    randposts.add(Post.objects.filter(category = randomcat).order_by('date')[0])
```

This may help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/

Comment: i don't want to use random categories. I need 5 of 50 categories that was recently updated. If all 10 latest posts i post into same category, on home page i need to show only one most recent post from this category and 4 recent posts from other categories that were updated - one post for each category.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let's try this again..

```
catsused = {}
posts = {}
postindex = 0
posts.add(Post.objects.order_by('date')[postindex])
catsused.add(Post.objects.order_by('date')[postindex].category

for each in range(1,5):
    postindex = postindex + 1
    post = Post.objects.order_by('date')[postindex] 
    while post.category in catsused:
        postindex = postindex + 1
        post = Post.objects.order_by('date')[postindex] 
    posts.add(post)
    catsused.add(post.category)

posts ## Now contains your posts
```

That seems like horrible code to me, but I suppose something close to that will do the job. You'll wanna add some code to handle "postindex" going over the number of posts there are in the system too.

Answer (score 1):

Using [order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) and [distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct):

```
Post.objects.all().order_by('category', 'date').distinct('category')
```

Then for performance adding index together on `category` and `date` fields.

But i think real production way is to use `Redis` to cache and update an id's list of latest posts of categories.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned up version of Doc's code:

```
catsused = {}
posts = {}

for post in Post.objects.order_by('date'):
    if post.category not in catsused:
        posts.add(post)
        catsused.add(post.category)
        if len(catsused) == 5:
            break
```