# Efficiently select latest items of different categories

Tags: django, performance, django-queryset

Consider the following model:

```
    class Data(Model):
        created_at = models.DateTimeField()
        category = models.CharField(max_length=7)
```

I want to select the latest object for all categories.

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429518/django-query-latest-posts-from-different-categories), i'm selecting the distinct categories and then making a separate query for each of them:

```
    categories = Data.objects.distinct('category').values_list('category', flat=True)
    for category in categories:
        latest_obj = Data.objects.filter(category=category).latest('created_at')
```

The downside of the approach is that it makes lots of queries (1 for the distinct categories, and then a separate query per category).

Is there a way to do this with a single query?

Comment: If you're not going to have a separated category model you might as well assign Data.objects.all() to a variable and run a function to retrieve the latest data per category, that's just one query

Comment: Btw to shorten your current code using a separate Category model:
`latest_objects = [obj.data_set.latest() for obj in Category.objects.all() if obj.data_set.count()]`

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would use a group by in relational database. Django has an aggergation API
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation) which allows you to do the following:

```
from django.db.models import Max
Data.objects.values('category').annotate(latest=Max('created_at'))
```

This will perform a single query and return a list like this:

```
[{'category' : 'cat1', 'latest' : '01/01/01' },{'category' : 'cat2' 'latest' : '02/02/02' }]
```

But I guess you might want to retrieve the data record id as well within this list. Django does not make thinks simple for you in this case. The problem is django uses all fields in the value clause to make the grouping and you cannot return extra columns from the query.

**EDIT**: I originally proposed to add a second values() clause to the end of the query based on web resources but this does not add extra columns to the result set.